# How to separate a column into threecolumns with R?

Tags: r, tidyr, separator

I have a data.frame where one of columns have such structure:
`"2019-09-11 13:29:55:647 INFO"`.

How could I separate this column into three columns, where:

- column 1 is :`"2019-09-11 13:29:55"`
- column 2 is: `"647"`
- column 3 is `"INFO"`.

I want to use `tidyr` separate function but can't write a regular expression for separators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `read.csv` after inserting a delimiter

```
cbind(df1, read.csv(text = sub("^(\\S+) (\\S+):([^:]+)$", 
         "\\1,\\2,\\3", df1$datetime), col.names =c('newcol1', 'newcol2', 'newcol3'),
      header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

---

If we are using `tidyverse`, specify the `sep` with a regex lookaround, i.e. to match `:` followed by characters that are not a `:` till the end or the space between two digits

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df1, datetime, into = c('newcol1', 'newcol2', 'newcol3'), 
        sep="(?<=\\d) (?=\\d)|:(?=[^:]+$)")
 #   newcol1  newcol2  newcol3
#1 2019-09-11 13:29:55 647 INFO
```

Or with `extract`, capture the characters as a group till the last `:` followed by digits till the end of the string

```
extract(df1, datetime, into = c('newcol1', 'newcol2', 'newcol3'), 
        "^(\\S+)\\s(.*):([^:]+)$")
#    newcol1  newcol2  newcol3
#1 2019-09-11 13:29:55 647 INFO
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(datetime = "2019-09-11 13:29:55:647 INFO", 
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: could you do it with tidyverse separate function?

Comment: sorry i wrote a column wrongly. its 2019-09-11 13:29:55:647 INFO  and separate into  2019-09-11 13:29:55 and 647 INFO

Comment: @EdZ  Do you need 3 columns or two?

Comment: three: 2019-09-11 13:29:55, 647, INFO